# How to convert A00073 value to 9973 in progress 4gl

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, 4gl

i have column having multiple value like A0045 ,A00065 . i want to convert it 9945, 9965.
Need to remove all 0 and character value and add 99 before that value.. Please help..

Comment: One of your examples has A00, the other has A000. How do you know the length of the number? For instance, if you had A00009, should that be 999 or 9909?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert A0058 value to 9958 in progress 4gl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929456/how-to-convert-a0058-value-to-9958-in-progress-4gl)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in many ways. Here is one way (may not be the best). As I don't have a database, I created a temp table.

```
def temp-table tt 
    field val as char.

create tt.
tt.val = "A0045".

create tt.
tt.val = "A00065".

for each tt:
    run filter_zero(input-output val).
    val = replace(val,"A","99").
    DISP val.
end.

procedure filter_zero:
    define input-output parameter val  as character.

    // remvoe all zeroes 
    repeat while val matches("*0*"): 
        val = replace(val,"0","").
    end.

end procedure.
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below removes the uppercase (A-Z) and lowercase letter (a-z) and "0" as well :

```
DEF TEMP-TABLE test
    FIELD str1 AS CHAR.

DEF VAR newStr AS CHAR NO-UNDO.
DEF VAR i AS INT NO-UNDO.

CREATE test.
ASSIGN test.str1 = "A0045".

CREATE test.
ASSIGN test.str1 = "A00065".

FOR EACH test:
    DO i = 65 TO 90: /* A - Z */
        IF SUBSTR(test.str1, 1, 1) EQ CHR(i) THEN
        DO:
            test.str1 = REPLACE(test.str1, CHR(i), "").       
        END.
    END.

    DO i = 97 TO 122: /* a - z */
        IF SUBSTR(test.str1, 1, 1) EQ CHR(i) THEN
        DO:
            test.str1 = REPLACE(test.str1, CHR(i), "").       
        END.
    END.

    /* Removes all 0 and add 99 before the value */
    test.str1 = REPLACE(test.str1, "0", "").
    ASSIGN test.str1 = "99" + test.str1.
    DISP test.
END.
```

Answer (score 0):

define variable word as character no-undo.

define variable i as integer no-undo.

assign word = "A00065".

/*******To Remove all the zero********/

word = replace(word,substring(word,index(word,"0"),(r-index(word,"0") - 1)),"").

do i = 65 to 90:
   if substring(word,1,1) = chr(i) then 
   do:

```
  word = replace(word,substring(word,1,1),"99").
  leave.
```

end.

end.

display word.

Answer (score 0):

```
  DEFINE VARIABLE word AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
    SET word.
    word =  REPLACE(word,SUBSTRING(word,1,R-INDEX(word,"0")),"99").   
    /* If you want to remove all words before last zero 
     (including last zero also)  * /

    MESSAGE word
        VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION BUTTONS OK.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do let me know if this works for you, Progress not installed so couldn't compile and test.

/* A0045 -> 9945
    A00065 -> 9965 */

```
DEFINE VARIABLE v_RawData AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE v_InpData AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE i         AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE j         AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.

ASSIGN v_RawData = "A0045,A00065".

DO i =1 TO NUM-ENTRIES(v_RawData):
    ASSIGN v_InpData = ENTRY(i,v_RawData).

    DO j = 1 TO LENGTH(v_InpData):
        IF ASC(SUBSTRING(v_InpData,j,1)) > 48 AND 
           ASC(SUBSTRING(v_InpData,j,1)) < 58 THEN
            DO:
                LEAVE.
            END.
    END.
    MESSAGE REPLACE(v_InpData,SUBSTRING(v_InpData,1,j - 1),"99").
END.
```

Comment: have you tested this.

Comment: @Billa - No as already said , didn't had progress installed in my PC so i had not tested it. But now i did. Thanks